# Read SVG File as text line by line

Tags: svg, swift4, line

I want to find circle data in an SVG file.
Reading the file:

```
let SVG_URL = openFile()
```

I check the URL with

```
guard let fileURL = SVG_URL else { return  }
```

in the do part I read the content with

```
let SVG_data = try String(contentsOf: fileURL, encoding: .utf8)
```

Printing SVG_data gives text like:

> ```
> <polyline
>       style="fill:none;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-width:2.797794"
>       id="9988D988"
>       points="126.55,50.950001 113.949963,43.750004 113.949963,43.749974 108.55,43.750004"/>
>   <g
>       id="4B4363F3">
>      <rect
>          style="fill:#F6F8FF;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-width:3.82"
>          id="2B4363F3"
>          x="228.070006"
>          y="714.069998"
>          width="2.16"
>          height="2.16"/>
>      <circle
>          style="fill:#F6F8FF;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-width:0.25"
>          id="3B4363F3"
>          cx="229.150231"
>          cy="715.150223"
>          r="1.018225"/>
>   </g>
> ```

Copying the text in MS Word shows line breaks after every line.

But

```
let SVG_text = SVG_data.components(separatedBy: "\n")
```

gives a simple line of text without line breaks. Same with "<" .

Converting SVG_text with

```
let SVG_array = Array(SVG_text)
```

gives me the wanted array, looking as

```
i: 40 zeile:       <g
i: 41 zeile:           id="4B4363F3">
i: 42 zeile:          <rect
i: 43 zeile:              style="fill:#F6F8FF;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-width:3.82"
i: 44 zeile:              id="2B4363F3"
i: 45 zeile:              x="228.070006"
i: 46 zeile:              y="714.069998"
i: 47 zeile:              width="2.16"
i: 48 zeile:              height="2.16"/>
i: 49 zeile:          <circle
i: 50 zeile:              style="fill:#F6F8FF;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-width:0.25"
i: 51 zeile:              id="3B4363F3"
i: 52 zeile:              cx="229.150231"
i: 53 zeile:              cy="715.150223"
i: 54 zeile:              r="1.018225"/>
i: 55 zeile:       </g>
```

what is what I want.

I think there must be a simpler way to do that.

Comment: Use an XML parser if you want to read an XML file.

Comment: thanks, solved my problem